# How to modify the frontend pages and footer text?

Tags: orocommerce

how I can edit orocommerce pages while in production, and how to edit the footer text.

I need to edit the pages and modify the footer text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By default, OroCommerce uses web catalogs to organize pages in the storefront.
   For more details, see https://doc.oroinc.com/user/concept-guides/content-management/web-catalog/#concept-guide-web-catalog.
2. You can configure the footer menu in the frontend menus management section: https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/frontend-menus/#backend-frontend-menus and change the footer copyright in the translations management section: https://doc.oroinc.com/user/back-office/system/localization/translations/#localization-translations